# how to sync online and offline databse

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, hyperlink, synchronization

I am working on an application (with WPF) that's going to be used to store data, the user should be able to access the data offline and the data should be synced online when there is an internet connection, so it can be accessed from a mobile app or from another device.

what are your suggestions to handle this case(any tools or methods), currently I am using Microsoft Access to make progress with the application design, but I can switch to something else if necessary. If you there is documentation or tutorial about this, please give me links because I'm new to databases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different scenario so that all of us can relate.

Pretend you have two mobile phones PhoneA and PhoneB. Both has facebook messenger app.  You turned off PhoneB. You use PhoneA  whole day to communicate with your friends.

At night You turned on PhoneB, and messenger app in phoneB pulls all the conversation from the server (data haven't exist on the phone yet).   So phoneB doesn't care what's on PhoneA,  PhoneB only pulls data that havent exist yet on its offline database.

The moral story is, You have to enhace your programming/algorithm techniques to check the existence of data on the offline database.   There are many ways and options to do it.  It comes down to programming practices.